# Issue with char[] in VS2008 - why does strcat append to the end of an empty array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am passing an empty char array that I need to recursively fill using `strcat()`. However, in the VS debugger, the array is not empty, it's full of some weird junk characters that I don't recognise. strcat() then appends to the end of these junk characters rather than at the front of the array.

I have also tried `encoded[0] = '\0'` to clear the junk before passing the array, but then strcat() doesn't append anything on the recursive call.

This is the code that supplies the array and calls the recursive function:

```
char encoded[512];
text_to_binary("Some text", encoded);
```

This is the recursive function:

```
void text_to_binary(const char* str, char* encoded)
{   
    char bintemp[9];
    bintemp[0] = '\0';

    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        ascii_to_binary(*str, bintemp);
        strcat(encoded, bintemp);
        str++;
        text_to_binary(str, encoded);
    }
}
```

What is going on?

ps. I can't use `std::string` - I am stuck with the `char*`.

**Edit:** This is the junk character in the array:
ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ...

Comment: encoded[0] = '\0' should work. Did you do this before calling text_to_binary?

Comment: The "junk character" is `0xcc` in hexadecimal.  Debug builds (under Visual C++) initialize stack variables with this value to help expose uninitialized variable usage when you are debugging.

Answer (score 6):

You are not initialising the array. Change:

```
char encoded[512];
```

to

```
char encoded[512] = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

strcat appends to the end of the string, the end is marked by a \0, it then appends a \0 to the new end position.

You should clear the destination encoded with either encoded[0]=0; or memset first.

Answer (score 2):

`char encoded[512];`.. `encoded` is not initialized and will contain junk (or 0xCCCCCCCC in debug builds).

Comment: `0xcd` is used by the debug heap.  `0xcc` is used for uninitialized variables on the stack.

Comment: All very compiler specific. If you mention this detail mention the compiler and OS at the same time.

Comment: My apologies.  Andreas's answer and my comment are both specific to the Microsoft Visual C++ debug runtime (at least since Visual Studio 2005).

Comment: The answer clearly states in the title that it's about VS2008; I don't believe it's necessary to state it in the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was due to encode initialization I think. A few comment on your program:

it's better to avoid recursive
   function when you can do it with a
   loop.

Second you should add the size of
   encoded to avoid possible overflow
   error (in the case the size of string
   is bigger than encoded).

```
void text_to_binary(const char* str, char* encoded)
{   
    char bintemp[9];
    bintemp[0] = '\0';
    encode[0] = '\0';

    for(const char *i = str; i!='\0'; i++)
    {
        ascii_to_binary(*i, bintemp);
        strcat(encoded, bintemp);
    }
}
```

PS: i didn't tried the source code, so if there is an error add a comment and I will correct it.

Good contination on your project.

Comment: yeah, thanks, i do know all of this, it's just a trivial example

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your immediate problem has been posted already, but your `text_to_binary` is still inefficient. You are essentially calling `strcat` in a loop with always the same string to concatenate to, and `strcat` needs to iterate through the string to find its end. This makes your algorithm quadratic. What you should do is to keep track of the end of `encoded` on your own and put the content of `bintemp` directly there. A better way to write the loop would be

```
while(*str != '\0')
{
    ascii_to_binary(*str, bintemp);
    strcpy(encoded, bintemp);
    encoded += strlen(bintemp);
    str++;
}
```

You don't need the recursion because you are already looping over `str` (I believe this to be correct, as your original code will fill `encoded` pretty weirdly). Also, in the modified version, `encoded` is always pointing to the end of the original `encoded` string, so you can just use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't attached source of ascii_to_binary, let's assume that it will fill buffer with hex dump of the char (if this is the case it's easier to use `sprintf(encoded+(i2),"%2x",*(str+i));`
2. What's the point of recursively calling text_to_binary? I think this might be a problem.